Using singleton instead of using context property breaks translation
I have a Python-QML communication setup using setContextProperty and I am trying to move to a setup that can be parsed by qmllint. As described in the docs (link) using a context property is invisible to all tooling including qmllint and recommends using a singleton instead. Indeed even the Qt6 book recommends exposing classes instead of objects by moving from setContextProperty to using qmlRegisterType.
Additionally, using the @QmlElement (doc) seems like an even cleaner way to do the same thing as qmlRegisterType.
The class I am exposing is an API through which I want to be able to set the application language. Using the old approach with setContextProperty, it works and translates the entire window instantly:
class MyAPI(QObject):
    def __init__(self, engine):
        super().__init__()
        self._engine = engine
    ... register some other properties
    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def retranslate(self, language=None):
        ...instantiate translator
        app=QtGui.QtGuiApplication.instance()
        if self._translator:
            app.removeTranslator(self._translator)
        app.installTranslator(newTranslator)
        if self._translator:
            self._engine.retranslate()
        self._translator = newTranslator

... then in my main function
    ... instantiate self.app & set some properties
    engine = QQmlAPPlicationEngine(parent=self.app)
    api=QmlApi(engine)
    api.retranslate()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("_api", api)
    engine.load("mymain.qml")
    return self.app.exec()

I can then simply call _api.retranslate anywhere in my QML and it works.
After moving to using the @QmlElement decorator with @QmlSingleton, I cannot pass the engine as a constructor argument so I made it a static variable that gets initialized once when needed. These are the parts that are different:
QML_IMPORT_NAME='io.qt.myapi'
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION=1

@QmlSingleton
@QmlElement
class MyAPI(QObject):
    _engine=None
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    ... register some other properties
    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def retranslate(self, language=None):
        ... same as before
        app.installTranslator(newTranslator)
        if self._engine is None:
            self._engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(parent=app)
        if self._translator:
            self._engine.retranslate()
        self._translator = newTranslator

... then in my main function
    ... instantiate self.app & set some properties
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(parent=self.app)
    api=QmlApi()
    api.retranslate()
    engine.load("mymain.qml")
    return self.app.exec()

This should then be used by QML as:
import io.qt.myapi

Item {
    MyAPI {
        id: _api
    }
    ... call _api.retranslate as before

However in this case translation is no longer instant. It seems to be quite messy, it only changes some strings in the application & only takes full effect after a restart. How can I recover the previous behaviour where translation was instant & complete, while keeping this @QmlElement approach which allows static analysis?

If MyAPI is a singleton, you should not be able to create a new instance within your qml. I'm surprised that doesn't give you an error. You reference singletons by their type name, so you would call MyAPI.retranslate() from qml, without creating an instance.

Why use muliple QQmlApplicationEngine instances? If you post a [mre], I'll answer the question.
